# getting 0 kb after backup the sql

Tags: php, mysqli

Why when i backup my sql the size is 0 kb what should i do ? or did i miss something? . and what is the code for recovering the sql. Thank you in advance

```
define("BACKUP_PATH", "D:\xampp/patient.sql");

$server_name   = "localhost";
$username      = "root";
$password      = "7831365";
$database_name = "patient";
$date_string   = date("Ymd");

$cmd = "mysqldump --routines -h {$server_name} -u {$username} -p{$password} {$database_name} > " . BACKUP_PATH . "{$date_string}_{$database_name}.sql";

exec($cmd);
```

Comment: Check if the command is correct and try executing it manually via SSH.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define your BACKUP_PATH like this:

```
define("BACKUP_PATH", "D:\xampp\patient_");
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:
escape characters

```
define("BACKUP_PATH", "D:\\xampp\\patient.sql");
```

check the response:

```
exec($cmd,$response);
print_r($response); //<-- might see the problem
```

Comment: Array ( ) that the system told me

Comment: also echo the $cmd and try to run exactly that line by your self and not with exec

Comment: mysqldump --routines -h localhost -u root -p7831365 patient > D:\xampp\patient.sql20150817_patient.sqlArray ( )